# List of PostParameters (Python Requests)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-requests

Hello So I have a list that I am trying to change the username and go down the list one at a time as it sends a request. For example I have a `finallist.txt` file that reads:

```
pop
boat
oreo
```

these are the list of usernames I want to send as the request. Here is my code:

```
    list = open("finallist.txt", 'r')
    paramsGet = {"Name": list}
    headers = {<ignore>}
    response = session.get("https://<ignore>.com/api/users/available", params=paramsGet, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        #
    elif response.status_code == 409:
        #
```

Note: I have all the required headers and syntax correct when the paramsGet - {"Name": pop}
but when I try to have it rotate down the list I am lost. I assume I must do for x in range 3 try:? I do not know sorry if I did not make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `for`-loop, for example:

```
# load every line from the file to list `lines`
with open("finallist.txt", 'r') as f_in:
    lines = [line for line in map(str.strip, f_in) if line]

# iterate over every line, change headers and do a request
for line in lines:
    print('Name {}'.format(line))
    paramsGet = {"Name": line}    
    headers = {}

    response = session.get("https://<ignore>.com/api/users/available", params=paramsGet, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        # handle status 200
    elif response.status_code == 409:
        # handle status 409
```

Note: Don't use variable name `list` - you're "shadowing" Python's builtin.